# how to implement Converse.js An XMPP chat client for asp.net 4.0 web site

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, converse.js

i just found one nice article about online chatting application with converse.js i read it's documentation and i like it. how ever i just have doubt it is there this chat facility can supported with asp.net 4.0 web site. Here i just want to know about in details is it supported with .net application.

here it's tells XMPP Chat server. Is there any additional cost for purchase it. After that how i setup this server for chat facility. here it's gives advice for identity i have to manually register user with it and i can use with my own web site.

Is there any one have idea how i implement this to my web site. Step By Step

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Asp.net so I am assuming you are talking about windows platform. I am using Openfire for XMPP messaging since last 5-6 years now and it is very easy to use and stable XMPP server. You can install it on your server and then configure Converse.js and XAMPP in conjunction with it to get web client chat feature. I referred this link to configure XAMPP along with Openfire: https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2954

Basic steps:
1. Install Openfire
2. Install XAMPP and configure as given in above link
3. Configure Converse.js in Asp.net application